# IIS reverse proxy not working in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I want to use a reverse proxy to point one of my endpoints to a resource that's hosted elsewhere. My primary server (where everything else is hosted) is in an Azure Web App and is otherwise working perfectly.

I've been using this seemingly failproof article along with the other links mentioned at the bottom of it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zhiliang_xus_blog/2016/01/19/build-a-google-reverse-proxy-site-on-azure-web-app-in-less-than-3-minutes/

As a baseline, I used a Web App with no additional code and confirmed that the reverse proxy works. This was done by manually creating/editing the `web.config` file and `applicationHost.xdt` file then restarting the server.

I've tried 3 separate approaches (all on clean, new web apps) all of which are failing for me:

1. Push my code, confirm it works, then follow the reverse proxy steps manually
2. Follow the steps manually, confirm reverse proxy works, then push my code
3. Put the reverse proxy files into my codebase and push everything at the same time

None of these 3 approaches are working. Is this a bug in Azure? How can I try to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this specific case was the location of my `web.config` file.

It needs to be in the root directory of the application which, in my case, was *not* `site\wwwroot`. My code was being generated and copied into `site\wwwroot\dist`. Putting the config file in that directory fixed the problem.

Additionally, there are logs that can be enabled to get some insight as to what's going on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Answer (score 1):

Post **XML Transformation (XDT)**, have you restarted the site?

I would suggest you to take a look at this blog from **Ruslan**:
http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/

It talks about using a Site extension. It implements the reverse proxy and it does the XDT transformation for you.

If the above is setup correctly, then there is something wrong with the URL Rewrite rules. I would recommend you to enable **Failed Request Tracing** and debug this further.

Answer (score 0):

The link/way you posted used URL Rewrite to implement a reverse proxy. I tested it and it worked fine with my empty web application. After published a web application to the Azure Web App(For example, an ASP.NET MVC web application), the URL Rewrite stopped working. The reason is that all the requests to your web application are routed by ASP.NET route module.

To enable URL Rewrite for some URLs, we need to disable ASP.NET route for these URLs. For example, if you want to rewrite all the requests with "product/xxx" format to another site. You could add following code to RouteConfig.cs file.

```
routes.Ignore("product/{action}");
```

Comment: What if I'm using node.js? Well, I'm not even (at this point) using the node server, just some npm modules to produce some static pages.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with node.js. The npm modules which used to produce static pages is worked as a router. You could try to find how to ignore a specific URL from these npm modules to fix your issue.

Comment: A workaround is creating a Virtual Directory and configure the URL Rewrite in this Virtual Directory.  To configure virtual applications and directories, you could specify each virtual directory and its corresponding physical path relative to the website root in Application Settings panel of Azure portal.

Comment: What do you mean the npm modules are "worked as a router"? We can basically forget about the Node part for now since we're just dealing with static pages. Pretend they were generated elsewhere and added to the codebase. Static pages that don't use ASP.NET or anything, how do I get those to play nicely?

Comment: I am a little confused of your issue. Could the URL Rewrite feature work fine or you just can't request the static pages on your web app?